# Run background native app or service using cordova

Tags: android, cordova

i have a native android app and i'm making another app using cordova and phonegap,
Is it possible when i open my cordova app it will run on background the other native app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think is to mix the native code for the core service with the Webbased UI.
you can take a look at [Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService](https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService)
but it is for android only.